# How can I fix an upload problem to my Arduino Nano 33 BLE Sense

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, uploading

When I try to upload an example code from the Arduino_LSM9DS1 Library it either jumps ports so the upload cannot complete or spits out some red text and never completes the upload, just gets stuck on uploading.

The red text is:

```
processing.app.debug.RunnerException
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:152)
    at cc.arduino.UploaderUtils.upload(UploaderUtils.java:77)
    at processing.app.SketchController.upload(SketchController.java:732)
    at processing.app.SketchController.exportApplet(SketchController.java:703)
    at processing.app.Editor$UploadHandler.run(Editor.java:2047)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: processing.app.SerialException: Error touching serial port 'COM4'.
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:107)
    at cc.arduino.packages.uploaders.SerialUploader.uploadUsingPreferences(SerialUploader.java:136)
    ... 5 more
Caused by: jssc.SerialPortException: Port name - COM4; Method name - openPort(); Exception type - Port busy.
    at jssc.SerialPort.openPort(SerialPort.java:164)
    at processing.app.Serial.touchForCDCReset(Serial.java:101)
    ... 6 more
```

I'm not that new to Arduino but I've never looked into uploading (I guess I should) and am struggling top get it to work.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Comment: This may be more suitable for [arduino.se] than here, as it's not related to debugging issues with your actual code.

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking the reset button seems changing the COM port.
I had the same problem and I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Clicking the reset button DOES change the COM port. I used com3 before, and after clicking the reset button, it became com4 and I couldn't find BLE33 any more... MY solution is to hold the reset button for about twenty seconds till the orange light shines. Then everything will be all right again.
By the way, I'm a Chinese.